# Swift 3 - SIGABRT error - numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview, sigabrt

Just updated to Swift 3 and xCode 8 Beta 4.

After fixing all the code issues I now have an error free project but it is throwing a SIGABRT error when clicking one particular button on my front screen.

I am sure that it is something to do with the UIPickerView  element on the destination page as I have deleted, checked and re added all segues and outlets to make sure everything is clear from that side.

The console is showing the following:

> 2016-08-02 18:59:46.607 ForceIt![38735:2895259]
>   -[ForceIt_.DirectoryViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcd68c0c210 2016-08-02
>   18:59:46.618 ForceIt![38735:2895259] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[ForceIt_.DirectoryViewController numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcd68c0c210'

The code from the relevant viewcontroller is as follows:

```
import UIKit

var forceSelectedForTabView = String()
var forceSelectedPositionInArray = Int()

class DirectoryViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var forcePicker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectedContactLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectedPhoneTextView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var selectedWebsiteTextView: UILabel!

    //function for the number of columns in the picker
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    //function counting the array to give the number of rows in the picker
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return forcePickerData.count
    }

    //function displaying the array rows in the picker as a string
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return forcePickerData[row]

    }

    //function allowing the font and colour of the picker to be changed
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let titleData = forcePickerData[row]
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 25.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.black])
        return myTitle
    }

    //function returning the selected row from the picker
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        forceSelectedForTabView = String(forcePickerData[row])
        forceSelectedPositionInArray = forcePickerData.index(of: forcePickerData[row])!


        self.selectedContactLabel.text = issiData[Int(forcePickerData.index(of: forcePickerData[row])!)]


        self.selectedPhoneTextView.text = phoneData[Int(forcePickerData.index(of: forcePickerData[row])!)]


        self.selectedWebsiteTextView.text = websiteData[Int(forcePickerData.index(of: forcePickerData[row])!)]

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `forcePickerData` equal to something? It seems like the problem is in `numberOfRowsInComponent` method

Comment: Its returning the count of an array that is providing the data for the picker. The array is located just below the end of the code shared above. 

It has been working perfectly under Xcode 7, however its proving a nightmare under Xcode 8...

Comment: In `numberOfRowsInComponent` call `print(forcePickerData.count)` is the output correct?

Comment: Its not giving any output - I assume I was right to add it before the `return` statement

Comment: Yeah it should be `print(forcePickerData.count)` and then `return forcePickerData.count`. When you do that it doesn't give you any output?

Comment: Nothing, just the same error - would it help to see the whole error log?

Comment: Then something is wrong with `forcePickerData`. Either it hasn't been instantiated or its empty

Comment: Ive added a set of break points  - one on each of the lines for the actions and one for the line before the first function is called - they run fine through the actions and show the counts for the arrays correctly. If I move the break point to just after the actions the error returns

Answer (score 9):

`numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` is a method declared in `UIPickerViewDataSource`, but your `DirectoryViewController` lacks `UIPickerViewDataSource` in its conforming protocol list.

Change the class header as:

```
class DirectoryViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
```

Without that, Swift cannot expose `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` from the method `numberOfComponents(in:)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix this issue by removing all previous code and inserting the methods again from the code library. There was nothing different in the new code, but it seems to have been accepted.

All is well again - guess I might have just angered a bug during the update process.